# array boundary checking and input validation

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am writing the hangman game in C++ and I was wondering how I can make sure that the word that my first user inputs just contains alphabetic characters, nothing else. I have to prompt the user to enter a new word when the word that they have already entered is not valid.

there are functions I use to do  that  but for some my check boundary function does not work properly. Please help, I have no idea how to fix it. In my first function I ask the user's input but and then I use another function to error check this word. 
word1 is the array that has stored my first word, and I assume that the letters are all in lower case for now . so I use the ASCII value of the characters to make sure that it is within the boundary. but say if I enter 45  it does ask me to reenter the word but the second word will be accepted no matter what it is . it could be |*%^% it accepts it anyway.

```
void CheckBound (char word1[], int SIZE1)
{
    int i;
    int w1[SIZE4];
    int found;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(word1);i++)
    {
       w1[i]=(int)word1[i];
       if (w1[i] >= 97 && w1[i] <= 122)
         found=1;
       else
       {
         printf("Please re-enter your word: ");
         fgets(word1, SIZE1, stdin);
         word1[strlen(word1)-1]='\0';
         printf("%s \n", word1);
       }
     }
     return;
   }
```

Comment: You can use `isalpha(w1[i])` and if required in combination with `&& islower(w1[i])` as per your requirement. You can find both functions in `#include <cctype>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you detect a non-alphanumeric character, you are still in the first loop iterating over each character of word1. Once the user has entered a new word, the loop continue with i!=0, which is of course incorrect.

Try this instead:

```
oid CheckBound (char word1[], int SIZE1)
{
    int i;
    bool ok = false;
    while(!ok)
    {
        ok = true;
        for (i=0;i<strlen(word1);i++)
        {
           int c = word1[i];
           if (c < 97 || c > 122)
           {
               ok = false;
               break;
           }
        }

        if(!ok)
        {
            printf("Please re-enter your word: ");
            fgets(word1, SIZE1, stdin);
            word1[strlen(word1)-1]='\0';
            printf("%s \n", word1);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, this is C, not C++.
typical C++ would use:

- std::string instead of char array/char pointers for storing strings
- std::vector, std::array for arrays (instead of plain C arrays)
- streams for printing and inputting text